# Вывести элементы списка постранично

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

у меня стоит задача - делать постраничный вывод списка, то есть допустим у нас есть номер страницы это `page1` и максимальное кол-во элементов на 1 странице это `10` как можно сделать так что бы при вводе нужной страницы допустим `page1` выводились первые 10 элементов списка, а при `page2` пропускались первые 10 элементов начального списка и брались уже следующие 10 элементов, я попытался как-то наскребать но у меня не получилось

Моя попытка:

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30]

items_per_page = 10
page = 1

index = items_per_page * page

for i, number in enumerate(array[:index], start=index+1):
    print(f"{i}. {number}")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно было добавить начало среза списка:

```python
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30]

page = 1
items_per_page = 10
index = items_per_page * page

for number in array[index-10:index]:
    print(number)
```